# classList.add Does Not Work

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm trying to make a simple to-do list thing using JavaScript. Basically, you enter an item to the input field, it gets added to the list, you click it if it's complete, then it gets crossed. If you click on a list that's already crossed out, that removes that line. But while removing a line works, adding a line through is not working.

HTML:

```
    <div><input type="text" value="" id="new_task"><button id="add_task">Add Task</button></div>

    <ul id="tasks">
        <li class="completed selected">One Task</li>
        <li>Two Task</li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">      
    /*local styles if any (quick tests and local only overrides)*/

    #tasks li{
        list-style: none;
    }

    #tasks .selected{
        list-style: disc;
    }

    .completed{
        text-decoration: line-through;
    }
</style>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var inputField = document.querySelector("#new_task");
    var myButton = document.querySelector("#add_task");
    var taskList = document.querySelector("#tasks");
    var newList = document.createElement("li"); 
    var completeTask = document.querySelector("li.completed.selected");
    var incompleteTask = document.querySelector("li:not([class])");

    myButton.onclick = function() {

    taskList.appendChild(newList);
    newList.innerHTML = inputField.value;
    inputField.value = "";
    }

    completeTask.onclick = function() {
    event.target.classList.remove("completed","selected");
    }

    incompleteTask.onclick = function() {
    event.target.classList.add("completed","selected");
    }




</script>
```

Comment: `classList` isn't supported by IE9 and lower. I suppose it's not what you're using? Because that `event` keyword looks suspicious...

Comment: What you need to call functions by elements' class is event delegation. Or you can have the event handlers check the element class and do the appropriate task.

Comment: @Musa: Could you elaborate more? Especially the second sentence. I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Check `incompleteTask` is actually referencing the elements you believe it does. It's possible your making the selection before the DOM has completed loading.

Comment: In my case more than one selector had that class, so make sure to see `document.querySelectorAll(selector)` if the correct element is selected

Comment: Also if you use className after classList.add, it overwrites classList.add, making it look like classList.add doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script parses the document only once and `document.querySelector("li.completed.selected")` returns a node. Therefore, removing those classes works only on the *One Task* which has those classes by the time the script is parsed.

you need to add `onclick` handler manually to every item created, see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6djrb/).

```
    var inputField = document.querySelector("#new_task");
    var myButton = document.querySelector("#add_task");
    var taskList = document.querySelector("#tasks"); 
    var lis = document.querySelectorAll("#tasks li");

function clickHandler() {
      if(event.target.classList.contains("completed"))
         event.target.classList.remove("completed","selected");
      else
         event.target.classList.add("completed","selected");
}

// add onclick handler to existing nodes
for(var i=0; i<lis.length; ++i) lis[i].onclick = clickHandler;

myButton.onclick = function() {
    var newList = document.createElement("li");
    taskList.appendChild(newList);
    newList.innerHTML = inputField.value;
    inputField.value = "";
    // add onclick handler to new nodes
    newList.onclick = clickHandler;

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use the `toggle` method of `classList` to swap the classes of you `li`s. Just select all your `li` and set their click event handler to a function that toggles the classes.

```
function ch() {
    this.classList.toggle("completed");
    this.classList.toggle("selected");
}

var items = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for (var x = items.length - 1; x >= 0; x--){
    items[x].onclick = ch;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RXH69/

Answer (score 0):

```
var element:any = document.querySelector('.' + ele[0].toUpperCase().toString())
console.log(element)`enter code here`
setTimeout(() => {
element.classList.add('classname');
}, 500);
```

I just used setTime out for this, and working fine.